# How to create and consume firestore data bundles - firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I installed the extension - Firestore Bundle Builder
and following some links

https://firebase.blog/posts/2021/04/firestore-supports-data-bundles/

and

https://firebase.google.com/docs/extensions/official/firestore-bundle-builder

```
BundleId = /bundles/products 
ClientCache = 7200 
ServerCache = 7200 
FileCache =7200 
Documents = ? 
Params = ?
```

If I have a firebase function

```
export const getAllProducts = functions.https.onCall(async (data, context) => {
  const {groceryType, packetSize} = data;
  const store = admin.firestore();

  let query = store.collection("products");

  if (groceryType !== "") {
    query = query.where("type", "==", groceryType);
  }
  query = query.where("size", "==", packetSize);
  query = query.limit(50);

  const querySnapshot = await query.get();

  const groceryItems = querySnapshot.docs.map((doc) => ({
    ...doc.data(),
    id: doc.id,
  }));

  return groceryItems;
});
```

and usage from client

```
export const getProducts = async (groceryType, packetSize) => {
    const getProductsFunction = firebase.functions()
        .httpsCallable('getAllProducts');
    const results = await getProductsFunction({groceryType,packetSize});
    return results.data;
}
```

What should I specify in "Documents" and in "Params" when making firestore bundle ?
Is it /getAllProducts? and params - groceryType, packetSize ?

How can I use my (google) cloud storage to save the bundle and use the bundle in the above function ?

Comment: I think firebase should have this feature as default, unless the only purpose of google is making money. I have seen the firebase conference video by Mr Duckworth.. Hope there is someone who implemented or created a course in linkedin learning or pluralsight